# Trouble with event delegation

Tags: javascript, html, event-delegation

I'm working with the mapbox geocoder plugin which is a search bar that populates suggestions of places while you type and displays them in a drop down. Essentially I'm working with dynamic list elements. I'm trying to use event delegation so when I click on a list item a function I created is fired.

Nothing is wrong with my function as I'm using it else where. I decided to try `console.log("Li has been clicked!!")` to verify if the list item was identifying my `'click'`. It is not and no errors are being thrown in the console. So I'm not sure exactly what is wrong.

Below is the snippet of html that is dynamically generated and my attempt at event delegation. Any help identifying what is wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

HTML:

```
<div class="suggestions-wrapper">
    <ul class="suggestions" style="display: none;">
        <li class=" active">
            <a>
                <div class="mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder--suggestion">
                    <div class="mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder--suggestion-title">844 Napa Valley Drive</div>
                    <div class="mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder--suggestion-address"> Fort Collins, Colorado 80525, United States of America</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
                <div class="mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder--suggestion">
                    <div class="mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder--suggestion-title">844 Courtenay Circle</div>
                    <div class="mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder--suggestion-address"> Fort Collins, Colorado 80525, United States of America</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('suggestions')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        plotIso();
        console.log("Li has been clicked!!")
    }
})
```

## **Solution:**

I changed `'click'` to `'mouseup'` in my application and also `'LI'` to `'DIV'` as suggested by @Menelaos Bakopoulos. Not sure why it accepts  'mouseup' and not 'click'. I'm assuming it has something to do with the way the mapbox geocode plugin is coded.

```
var searchSugg = document.getElementsByClassName('suggestions')[0];
searchSugg.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "DIV") {
        plotIso();
        console.log("Li has been clicked!!")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the condition on the "LI" means you must click the actual dot. 
If you don't click the bullet or dot, nothing happens.

You need to change this condition.

I commented out your IF statement, and this does display the console.log and alert that I added.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('suggestions')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
       alert("Li has been clicked!!")
        console.log("Li has been clicked!!")
   // }
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/menelaosbgr/ftbpyLr9/3/

### Update

As stated by the OP, changing LI to DIV solves the problem:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('suggestions')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        //if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "DIV") {
           alert("Li has been clicked!!")
            console.log("Li has been clicked!!")
       // }
    })
```

Comment: I changed LI to DIV and works as it should in jsFiddle but for some reason it's not console logging the text in my application, but thank you for this explanation. Something else must be the culprit.

Comment: I changed 'click' to 'mouseup' in my application and everything is working. Not sure why it accepts  'mouseup' and not 'click'. I'm assuming it has something to do with the way the mapbox geocode plugin is coded.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't to necessarily click on **DOT or BULLET of LI**, you could click on the **a>, div> (the childrens of li>)**. So the condition ***e.target.nodeName == "LI"*** isn't good enough. I recommend you the snippet as following :

```
function findClosest(el, selector) {
    if (!Element.prototype.closest) { // Older browsers
        let e = el;
        while (e) {
            if (selectorMatches(e, selector)) {
                return e;
            }
            e = e.parentElement;
        }
    }
    // Modern browsers
    return el.closest(selector);
}

document.getElementsByClassName('suggestions')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let ele = e.target; // ele is always available here because the event click is fired
    let liClicked = findClosest(ele, 'li'); // get enclosed <LI> of ele clicked
    if(liClicked) {
        plotIso();
        console.log("Li has been clicked!!", liClicked);
    }
})
```